# clang++ compile with wrong output info

Tags: c++, qt, android-ndk

I had a problem when compiler a qt-andorid project after I finish my qt compiler environment with ndk20, the console output clang++ error no such file or director 'obj/moc_SimulaePosition.obj' (miss the character 't') .  But strange that the sourcefile(class)  SimulatePosition.h(Q_OBJECT)  SimulatePosition.cc in qgroundcontrol.pro  and Makefile is right.

1.change the ndk version with ndk19,ndk13 failed

2.change the qt version with qt11 ,qt12  failed

3.change  moc_SimulatePosition.obj to moc_SimulaePosition.obj  pass

qgroundcontrol.pro

```
***
HEADERS += ***
        src/PositionManager/SimulatedPosition.h \
        ***
SOURCES += ***
        src/PositionManager/SimulatedPosition.cc \
        ***
***
```

Makefile

```
***
obj\moc_SimulatedPosition.obj: moc\moc_SimulatedPosition.cpp 
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o obj\moc_SimulatedPosition.obj moc\moc_SimulatedPosition.cpp

obj\SimulatedPosition.obj: F:\code\C\qgroundcontrol-local\src\PositionManager\SimulatedPosition.cc 
OBJECTS       = ***
              obj\SimulatedPosition.obj \ 
          obj\moc_SimulatedPosition.obj \
              ***
***
```

how to fix the problem and show the right info

Comment: This looks like an issue while linking, can you provide the config for that as well?

Comment: Tks! The Makefile point that the link obj is moc_SimulatedPosition.obj  ,but the compiler output another error with a uncomprehensive obj name .  Makefile as follow: